# SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'teamName' cannot be null

Tags: php, mysql

so I'm trying to fill my tables up with data but I keep getting this error:

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column
>   'teamName' cannot be null

The strange thing is that If I echo out $myarray[1] it loops through and prints each team name fine, so I don't understand why I'm having so many issues reading the data in? The array evidently isn't containing a null?

here's the creation of the table:

```
$createQuery ="CREATE TABLE TeamTable
(
    teamID  INT(6) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    teamName    VARCHAR(60) NOT NULL,
    Flag        BLOB,
    Country VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,

    PRIMARY KEY(teamID)
)";
$pdo->exec($createQuery);
```

Here is where I'm trying to insert into the table:

```
$filet = fopen("team.csv", "r");
while(!feof($filet))
{
$myarray = fgetcsv($filet);

$insertTeamQuery ="INSERT into TeamTable(teamName, Country, Flag) VALUES(:val1,:val2,:val3)";
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($insertTeamQuery);
echo $myarray[1];
$stmt->execute(array(':val1' => $myarray[1], ':val2' => $myarray[2], ':val3' => $myarray[3]));
$stmt->execute();
 }
 fclose($filet);
```

I checked on PHPmyadmin and there is meant to be 6 teams, but I have 2 of each team which is odd? not sure why it's putting the same values in twice per loop either? But it's obviously filled the table up if it's filled there so I don't understand this error with it saying it's null? Been struggling with this one for quite a while now

If anyone has any idea what's wrong I would greatly appreciate some help, thanks in advance! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because you have executed twice,

```
$stmt->execute();
```

remove this line and your code will work properly

Comment: Oh right, of course, my bad, that's fixed the duplication issue, thanks, but the other error at the top of my original post still persists, even tho in the PHPMyAdmin view the table looks filled in as I would expect? I'm struggling to understand how "TeamName" is null when in the table all 6 of my teams have a team name filled in? yet I'm still getting the error.

Comment: can you please add  `print_r($stmt->errorInfo());` after `execute` and share what it shows other than specified error

Comment: Here's the output:



Array ( [0] => 00000 [1] => [2] => ) Array ( [0] => [1] => [2] => ) Array ( [0] => 00000 [1] => [2] => ) Array ( [0] => [1] => [2] => ) Array ( [0] => 00000 [1] => [2] => ) Array ( [0] => [1] => [2] => )

Comment: try with static values with out while

Comment: When I remove the while loop the original error disappears, but here's the output:

Array ( [0] => 00000 [1] => [2] => )

I think the issue could be that it's trying to loop through a 7th time? Not sure why since theres only 6 rows but that is the only thing I could think it could be

Comment: That means you have issue with `$myarray` , first resolve the looping then try with insert.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the  `insert` to keep working, you can try using `INSERT IGNORE`

`INSERT into TeamTable (teamName, Country, Flag) VALUES (:val1,:val2,:val3);`

The `set` part does nothing -- the value doesn't change -- but the effect is to ignore the error.

Comment: Do you think that is a good option at this point? I'm just confused since the table seems filled in as I would expect within the PHPMyAdmin page yet apparently there are NULL values in TeamName?